# Is it possible to prevent SQL injection without prepared statements (Node.js & MSSQL)

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, node.js, sql-injection

Is it acceptable to simply escape dangerous characters from user input and then run the SQL query directly, rather than using prepared statements?

For example, could I just use the following function on the input, build the query and then execute it?

```
function mysql_real_escape_string (str) {
    return str.replace(/[\0\x08\x09\x1a\n\r"'\\\%]/g, function (char) {
        switch (char) {
            case "\0":
                return "\\0";
            case "\x08":
                return "\\b";
            case "\x09":
                return "\\t";
            case "\x1a":
                return "\\z";
            case "\n":
                return "\\n";
            case "\r":
                return "\\r";
            case "\"":
            case "'":
            case "\\":
            case "%":
                return "\\"+char; // prepends a backslash to backslash, percent,
                                  // and double/single quotes
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: may be this could help you https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values

Comment: This is definitely a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/346723), there should never be a situation in which running a query directly and manually trying to avoid injection is safer or better than preparing the statement. What do you need this for?

Comment: Basically, I have spent all day trying to figure out how to use prepared statements (for Node.js and MSSQL) and I haven't had much luck. (I am a newbie to this). I was hoping for an easy alternative.

Comment: `mysqljs` is one of the library providing preparedstatement and also escaping methods

Comment: For Turing complete versions of SQL, preventing SQL injection for all possible inputs would be equivalent to solving the halting problem.

Answer (score -1):

Create Stored Procedure. Build a Data Access Layer/Service. Call methods on the service from the app passing appropriate method parameters from the application.

In my Angular code I call from a data repository layer implemented as a service injected in my components.